# Finding only 1x repeating elements in chain?

Tags: c

Have a few questions regarding my code and in general about working with strings.
So about my code, user inserts string, ( for example: ABCDEBCC ), and it should output only symbols that repeated once ( in this case only symbol "B" since C repeated 2x and rest didnt repeat at all).

Questions

1. What to add to my code so it checks if symbol repeats only 1x, at the moment it just checks for repeating symbols as you can see.
2. Why does it  checks A and a as different?
3. What should I add so it checks for space symbol as well?
4. Should I rather use pointers than indexes when working with strings?

Code:

```
#define symbol_count 100

int main()
{
    char text[symbol_count];
    int size;
    int i,j,repSimb,fail;
    printf("String\n\n");
    printf("Insert a string: ");
    gets(text);
    size = strlen(text);
    printf("\nInserted string:    ");
    puts(text);
    for(i=0;i<size; ++i)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if(text[i]==text[j])
            {
                printf("Symbols in string that repeat only 1x\n  %c",text[i]);
            }
        }
    }        
    getche();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly *not* how this should be approached. Assuming your string is *nly* letters, consider instead having:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#define NUM_CHARS  ...  /* number of characters (no, I don't remember the exact number :-) */

int counts[NUM_CHARS]

memset(counts, 0, sizeof(counts); /* clear the array */

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (!isalpha(line[i]))
        continue;  /* not a letter */

    char c = toupper(line[i]);

    counts[c - 'A']++;
}

/* at this point you have counts for each character, so you can output only ones 
   with count == 2 */
```

This can be extended to other character classes.

Comment: String may consist space symbols as well, for example "A B ADEF" in this case it should return "A " letter and a space symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toupper` to make a character uppercase - that'll be good for case insensitive comparisons.

As for "only one match" you will need to count each character and output that. I would recommend storing the counts in an array, or if you feel up to it a [map](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/&ei=MlOWUrnaF5OQhQeH1YCAAQ&usg=AFQjCNF1P91QqM1mi_HI3CRR2HvkIfiqnw&sig2=EcGjOiTD9sQ72aeukhESEg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.ZG4) (although that would be C++).